Firebase function suddenly stopped working
I deployed a Firebase function 6 months ago. It has been working fine for the last 6 months. But suddenly, in the last 4 days, it has stopped working. When calling the API, it returns a 500 error code with the message <h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>.
When I try to see the logs, there are no logs for the API call. So when I try to redeploy the function it starts giving some permission error in the Firebase function service account, I am attaching a screenshot below.
I tried to permit the service account. but still, the response to deployment is the same.

